# Chart colors change when copying worksheet to a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 workbook containing a wide variety of charts that are used in our reporting. I've written VBA code to copy selected worksheets to a new workbook using:

```
XLMaster.Sheets(x).Copy after:=XLClinic.Sheets(XLClinic.Sheets.Count)
```

However, when I do so, the colors in the charts change.

They also change if I copy the worksheet 'manually' by opening XLMaster, right clicking the worksheet name and selecting Move/Copy.

How do I keep the colors set in XLMaster when copying to XLClinic?

Comment: How are the colors defined? I suspect the color palette in `XLMaster` is not the same as in `XLClinic`.

Comment: I'm quite certain that the colors in XLMaster have not been selected from a palette, but selected based on the personal preference of the one who did the formatting. Can I create a palette from these color selections and copy that to XLClinic?

Comment: Yes. Example: suppose one of the lines on the chart is red. In the workbook containing `XLClinic` you can set the color palette index `0` as red using `Workbooks("yourbook.xls").Colors(0) = vbRed`. Then in your code set the colorindex of the line to 0. This will make keep the color consistency between workbooks

Comment: Does that mean I need to manually edit every chart to use color palette (0) if I want that red color, then manually (via VBA) copy those palette settings to the new workbook?

Comment: What I would do is loop over the colors in the chart, get the color index and corresponding color (e.g. `RGB`, vbConstant) and then use that to update the destination color palette. That way nothing is manual.

Comment: Does it matter that these are charts on a regular worksheet, not on a chart-worksheet? (we're going to hit the 'Quit chatting in comments' warning soon...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73102/discussion-between-freeman-and-alex-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue that's confounded the entire internet. I ended up writing a routine to copy all the series colors from the source to the destination:

```
i = 0
j = 0
For Each ChartObj In Master.ChartObjects
  ReDim Preserve Titles(i)
  ReDim Preserve Charts(i)
  Titles(i) = ChartObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text
  Charts(i) = ChartObj.Chart.Name
  For Each Ser In ChartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
    ReDim Preserve R(j)
    ReDim Preserve G(j)
    ReDim Preserve B(j)
    R(j) = Ser.Interior.Color Mod 256
    G(j) = Ser.Interior.Color \ 256 Mod 256
    B(j) = Ser.Interior.Color \ 65536 Mod 256
    j = j + 1
  Next
  i = i + 1
Next

j = 0
For Each ChartObj In Clinic.ChartObjects
  For i = LBound(Titles) To UBound(Titles)
    If Titles(i) = ChartObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text Then
      For Each Ser In ChartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        Ser.Interior.Color = RGB(R(j), G(j), B(j))
        j = j + 1
      Next
      i = UBound(Titles) + 1
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Not exactly ideal, but it works. I do realize that this relies on finding the source and destination charts in the same order for the colors to be applied correctly. So far, in limited testing, it's worked OK. I'll have to update if I find worksheets where the charts end up being in a different order after copying.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier reapply the colors to a chart before it is copied, and you don't need to round trip it through the RGB algorithms. Select a chart and run this:

```
Sub RecolorChartFills
  Dim srs As Series
  For Each srs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
     srs.Format.Fill.Forecolor.RGB = srs.Format.Fill.Forecolor.RGB
  Next
End Sub
```

This keeps the same colors, but unlinks then from the utterly confusing color theme system introduced in Office 2007. The above works on bar, column, and area charts, which use a fill format. Line and scatter charts use lines and also marker background and foreground colors.

Comment: Am I missing something? Your code inside the `For`...`Next` loop is effectively `x = x`.

Comment: When the color is first applied, it's not applied as RGB, it's applied as a theme color and a brightness level. But I can read the RGB of the theme/brightness-applied color (on the right of the equals sign) and reapply this color as RGB, not theme/brightness, to the same series I just read it from (on the left).

Comment: Told you it was confusing.

Comment: Thanks, it took nearly a month for that to sink in, but it finally did. Your solution didn't seem to do the job, as the colors were already borked by the time they were on the destination sheet, but it did lead me to the solution I came up with.

Comment: Maybe you should apply my code snippet before moving the chart to the other sheet.